# Removing dups from unsorted linkedlist two loops returning no output Python

Tags: python, duplicates

For some reason my code is returning nothing. The print function works properly and returns a linked list. But once I run my removedup function I get nothing. I am suspicious of the arguements it takes in, self. But it doesnt seem to work with head or node either. Any suggestions?

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def printing(self):
        tempPrint = self.head
        while tempPrint.next is not None:
            print(tempPrint.data)
            tempPrint = tempPrint.next
        print(tempPrint.data)    
        
    def removedups(self):
    
    
        curr = self.head
    
        while curr.next is not None:
            curr2 = curr
            while curr2.next is not None:
                if (curr.data == curr2.next.data):
                    tempDup = curr2
                    curr2.next = curr2.next.next
                else:
                    curr2 = curr2.next
        curr = curr.next       
        
        
node = LinkedList()
node.head = Node(1)
n1 = node.head
n2 = Node(2)
n3 = Node(2)
n4 = Node(4)
n5 = Node(5)
n6 = Node(5)
n7 = Node(7)
n8 = Node(8)
n1.next = n2
n2.next = n3
n3.next = n4
n4.next = n5
n5.next = n6
n6.next = n7
n7.next = n8

node.removedups()
node.printing()
```

Comment: You're missing an indent on the last line of removedups, `curr = curr.next`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding kcsquared ! My last line of dups function was outside of the appropriate while loop so " curr = curr.next " needs to be indented.